# I want to open my FTP server page using Android Browser Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, ftp, ftp-client, ftpwebrequest

I use the following Code but the app just crashes as URI.Parse don't know how to handle ftp:/

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(LinkUrl.get("ftp:/192.168.0.103")));

startActivity(intent);
```

LOG Cat as Follows (The part that raised Exception):

```
2019-12-22 03:04:25.877 8018-8018/com.example.webview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.webview, PID: 8018
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.webview/com.example.webview.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=ftp:///... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Very few devices will have an app that supports the `ftp` scheme, as FTP is unpopular and insecure. You will need to catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` and gracefully handle the case where the user lacks an app that supports the `ftp` scheme.